# Numerical stability of argument of complex number / branch cuts

Tags: python, c++, precision, floating-accuracy, complex-numbers

I am implementing a numerical evaluation of some analytical expressions which involve factors like `exp(1i*arg(z) / 2)`, where `z` is in principle a complex number, which sometimes happens to be *almost* real (i.e. to floating point precision, e.g. `4.440892098500626e-16j`).

I have implemented my computations in Python and C++ and find that sometimes results disagree as the small imaginary part of the "almost real" numbers differ slightly in sign, and then branch cut behaviour of `arg(z)`(i.e. `arg(-1+0j) = pi`, but `arg(-1-0j) = -pi`) significantly changes the result … I was wondering if there is any commonly used protocol to mitigate these issues?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you care if the phase is `pi` or `-pi`? If it is a phase, and you use it as such, you shouldn't care at the range of the phase; i.e. you have to cut somewhere. Anyway, if, for some reason, you depend on that, why cannot you "normalize" the phase into the range you want?

Comment: There is always `fmod(arg(z)+2*pi, 2*pi)`.

Comment: @Acorn, I do not care about +pi or -pi, but some terms depend on `exp(1i*arg(z) / 2)`, so that the phase +pi/2 or -pi/2 matters …

Comment: @Faser: Those terms themselves have branch cuts (just like `csqrt` does).  If the difference matters, you have to consider the multivalued function or else move the branch cut.